# If two vectors are uncorrelated should they be uncorrelated to a other unequal vector?

Tags: correlation

I have a dataset which has a lot of vectors that are not equal to each other. I would like to confirm that they are all independent and uncorrelated. Just in the interest of making this task easier?

Is it safe to assume that **if $Cor(X,Y) = 0$ and $Cor(X,Z) = 0$ then $Cor(Y,Z) = 0$?**

Answer (score 3):

No, the assumption is not correct.

A counterexample is when $Y=kZ$ where $k \ne 0$  and hence $cor(X,Y)=cor(X,Z)$ but $Cor(Y,Z)  \ne 0$.

Comment: Since user specifically says vectors are unequal you might want to complicate the counter example slightly and let $Z=AY$ with $A$ some deterministic transform.

Comment: oops, i missing the unequal part. thanks.

Comment: Thank you Siong for helping me with this.